# Filter array using forEach

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I got an array of dates, where I want to filter out specific days.
That's my previous solution, which works fine:

```
var available = dates.filter(function(e) {
  return (
    e.getDay() != 0 && // sunday
    e.getDay() != 6 && // saturday
    e.getDay() != 2 && // tuesday
    e.getDay() != 3 && // wednesday
  );
});
```

Now, I want to make this dynamic. So I got an array like this:

```
var unavailable = [0, 2, 3, 6]
```

And then I try to filter out those days like this:

```
unavailable.forEach(function(x){
  available = dates.filter(function(e, index){
    return e.getDay() != x;
  });
});
```

That doesn't appear to be working tho. What did I do wrong and how can I get this to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats dates in the code?

Comment: You have to do it the other way round: `dates.filter(function() { /* check if .getDay() is part of the array stored in unavailable */ })`

Comment: What is `dates` array

Comment: @the_ultimate_developer I didn't include the date array in my question, since it's just an array generated like this `[new Date("2019-03-07"), new Date("2019-03-09"), ...]` and then turns to `[Mon Apr 01 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0200, Tue Apr 02 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0200, ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swith the order of comparing and return the result of the check. In this case you need [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead of [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), because you need a result for the filtering.

```
available = dates.filter(function(e, index) {
    return unavailable.every(function(x) {
        return e.getDay() != x;
    });
});
```

The same with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and a negation of the returned result and a negated comparison.

```
available = dates.filter(function(e, index) {
    return !unavailable.some(function(x) {
        return e.getDay() === x;
    });
});
```

A shorter approach.

```
var unavailable = [0, 2, 3, 6]
    available = dates.filter(e => !unavailable.includes(e.getDay()));
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to use `forEach` use `filter` and `includes`

```js
var unavailable = [0, 2, 3, 6]
var dates = ['1-1-2019', '1-2-2019', '1-3-2019', '1-4-2019',' 1-5-2019', '1-6-2019', '1-7-2019', '1-8-2019',' 1-9-2019'];
workingDays = dates.filter(e => {
return !unavailable.includes(new Date(e).getDate())})
console.log(workingDays)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I accepted Ninas answer tho, because it's more detailed. +1 tho :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the right answer for you.

```
let unavailable = [0, 2, 3, 6];
available = dates.filter(e => !unavailable.includes(e.getDay());
```

The problem with your code is that for each element in *unavailable* array, you are resetting *available*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
available = dates.filter(function(e) {
  return unavailable.indexOf(e.getDay()) === -1 ? true : false;
})
```

The problem with your code is that `forEach` rewrites the value of available every iteration, and your program adds difficulty to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not rigid to create an array and is not going to be used anywhere else in your code then no need to.

```js
dates.filter(e => e.getDay().toString().match(/0|6|2|3/));
```